# Object versions ordering

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Does GCS provide any guarantees about object versions ordering when [listing objects with their archived versions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#list)? Can we rely that newer versions come before older ones?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Archived objects are returned ordered by their generation number.

Comment: Thanks! However, as far as I know, there are [no ordering guarantees for generation numbers](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/gs-announce/XdSq25nsHio/-GuZxzyOAwAJ).